# Is it possible to create a thumbnail with the FileReader API?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the proof-of-concept I need for loading in multiple images with [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL).

However, my clients' workflow is such that they load in hundreds of images at a time which crashes the browser.

Is there any way to load in these images in as actual thumbnails (16k vs 16Mb)?

Comment: Just use the url pointing to the thumb instead

Comment: There isn't a thumbnail on the local machine. Only the hi-resolution original image.

Comment: you are saying that there is no server and the application only runs client side? anyway you should create a thumbnail somehow, probably as part of the process of importing images in the app

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing with the images but you could potentially use `window.URL.createObjectURL` instead which would give you greater control of when to release the memory after an image is done uploading or whatever.  It will also produce a much smaller footprint in the document since it's an actual url rather than a base64 string.

Comment: See mdn [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL).  And an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images) that shows [releasing memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL) and creating a preview.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use a FileReader, at all.

Instead, to display any data from a Blob, use the URL.createObjectURL method.
FileReader will load the binary data thrice in memory (one when reading the Blob for conversion, one as Base64 String and one when passed as 
the src of your HTMLElement.)
In case of a file stored on the user-disk, a blobURL will load the data only once in memory, from the HTMLElement. A blobURL is indeed a direct pointer to the Blob's data.

So this will already free a lot of memory for you.

```js
inp.onchange = e => {
  for(let file of inp.files) {
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    let img = new Image(200);
    img.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="file" webkitdirectory accepts="image/*" id="inp">
```

Now, if it is not enough, to generate thumbnails, you could draw all these images on canvases and reduce their size if needed.
But keep in mind that to be able to do so, you'd have to first load the original image's data anyway, and that you cannot be sure how will browser cleanup this used memory. So might do more harm than anything by creating these thumbnail versions.

Anyway, here is a basic example of how it could get implemented:

```js
inp.onchange = e => {
  Promise.all([...inp.files].map(toThumbnail))
    .then(imgs => document.body.append.apply(document.body, imgs.filter(v => v)))
    .catch(console.error);
};

function toThumbnail(file) {
  return loadImage(file)
    .then(drawToCanvas)
    .catch(_ => {});
}

function loadImage(file) {
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const img = new Image();
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    img.onload = e => res(img);
    img.onerror = rej;
    img.src = url;
  });
};

function drawToCanvas(img) {
  const w = Math.min(img.naturalWidth, 200);
  const r = w / img.naturalWidth;
  const h = img.naturalHeight * r;
  const canvas = Object.assign(
    document.createElement('canvas'), {
      width: w,
      height: h
    }
  );
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
  return canvas;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" webkitdirectory accepts="image/*" id="inp">
```